# JavaScript Letter replacing code, not replacing capitals?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to complete a codewars challenge as my practice coding since I will have a beginner tech test to enter a coding training program. In case you would like to know what the challenge is: https://www.codewars.com/kata/530e15517bc88ac656000716/train/javascript

I have written code which does what is expected. I will quote Codewars.com below:

> ROT13 is a simple letter substitution cipher that replaces a letter
> with the letter 13 letters after it in the alphabet. ROT13 is an
> example of the Caesar cipher.
>
> Create a function that takes a string and returns the string ciphered
> with Rot13. If there are numbers or special characters included in the
> string, they should be returned as they are. Only letters from the
> latin/english alphabet should be shifted, like in the original Rot13
> "implementation".

My code grabs the test string `"grfg"` and converts it to the word `"test"` which would be the equivalent to 13 letters ahead in the alphabet, however, if I pass the string as `"Grfg"` with the capital `"G"`it returns `"gest"` meaning that it will not replace capital letters.

If I pass `"test"` in lower case it will return `"grfg"`, so it works backwards too, however, if I pass `"Test"` it will return `"trfg"` not replacing the capital again but returning the same letter.

Please find the code I wrote below:

```
    function rot13(message){
      let abc = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", 
 "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z",   "a", "b",  "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
      let msg = message.split("");
    
      for (let i = 0; i < abc.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < abc.length; j++) {
            if (msg[j] === abc[i]) {
              
              ind = parseInt(abc.indexOf(i), 0) + 13;
              msg[j] = abc.slice(i + 13, i + 14);
                   
          };
        };
      };
      
      return msg.join("").toLowerCase();
    };
    
    rot13("test");
```

What is my mistake or what I should know to make sure that my code will convert the strings regardless of capitals or lowercase?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the `message` all lower-case first, before splitting it?

`let msg = message.toLowerCase().split("");`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought of doing so, however, what I would really like to understand is why would capitals not get replaced. :)

Comment: Because you don't have upper case letters in the `abc` array at all :)
The comparison function (===) is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just changed the === to == and now the function just does not return anything.

Comment: `a` and `A` are of the same type, they are both `strings`, but its different ASCI values, so regardless of number of equals it's always a different thing.